# Edit mode required first for Texture Paint to work

Tags: texture-painting

When I have multiple textures to paint on then I need to go to edit mode first before I can paint on them.
Here I show what is going on:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=biUbiMUzCHE

Why is the first going to edit mode required? It is really confusing, especially for new users cause there is nothing indicating why texture paint is not working when you not went to edit mode.

I hope someone can explain.

Comment: Please include a screen capture showing your Side Bar with appears with the letter N in texture paint node.  Select tool from the Side bar and from there you can use texture slots with mode Material or Single Image.  It will help you to use those items.  That is a more clear means of selecting a destination image.

Comment: If you think the behavior you describe is an error. then you can report it.  Others can comment on that.

Comment: In Blender 2.91 there is a small notification on the screen when no texture is selected.

Answer (score 0):

Try mixing the colors in the shader editor first, then from the 3D Viewport switch to Texture Paint mode (**Ctrl**+**Tab**, **9**).
In Texture Paint mode from the Properties Panel (**N**), select the Tool tab.
Select the base material, then you can select which texture you would like to paint on from here.[image]